# onTriggerExit2D() not working? unity2D c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making an A.I character walk towards the player. Once it's collider2D enters the players by using Add force and that works fine and dandy, but when the A.I exits the players collider2D it keeps adding the force. So I added onTriggerExit2D() to either make the force 0 or to stop applying it.

For some reason the trigger is never exited I have used debugging but nothing ever shows.

```
void Update () {

    if (canHearPlayer) 
    {
        rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2 (-force, 0));
    }
    if (!canHearPlayer) 
    {
        force = 0;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate() 
{
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
    Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " was hit by " + other.gameObject.name);

    if (other.gameObject.name == "New_Player") 
    {
        canHearPlayer = true;
        force = 3f;
    }
}

void onTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "New_Player") 
    {
        canHearPlayer = false;
        Debug.LogWarning (canHearPlayer + "Trigger has been exited");
    }
}
```

Comment: typo? OnTriggerExit2D needs a capital "O"

Answer (score 4):

The function isn't working because the letter "o" is lowercase instead of uppercase.

Change this line:

```
void onTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
```

to:

```
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
```

Comment: Thanks i just had a second pair of eyes and they noticed it for me, even googled it to see if i spelt it correct and still never notcied the "O" lol thanks for the reply!